# List Nested Data Type Sum

Tags: haskell

I have this type

```
data List a = EmptyL | ConsL a (List (a,a))
```

and I wrote this function

```
lenL :: List a -> Int
lenL EmptyL = 0
lenL (ConsL x xs) = 1 + lenL xs
```

Can I write a function like this?

```
sumL :: List Int -> Int
```

How?

Comment: What have you tried? If you were able to write length in terms of recursion, can you extend that approach to sum?

Comment: It is not really clear to me why you write `List (a,a)` as recursive part, instead of `List (a,a)`, it makes not much sense in my opinion.

Comment: @Norrius It is not that simple, since the `List` type is not a regular list. It recurs as `List (a,a)`, exploiting polymorphic recursion.

Comment: Of course it is not a regular list, I'm trying to understand nested datatypes.

Answer (score 9):

Sure:

```
data List a = EmptyL | ConsL a (List (a,a))

pair f (x, y) = (f x, f y)

nest :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
nest f EmptyL       = EmptyL
nest f (ConsL x xs) = ConsL (f x) (nest (pair f) xs)

sumL :: List Int -> Int
sumL EmptyL       = 0
sumL (ConsL x xs) = x + sumL (nest (uncurry (+)) xs)
```

We have:

```
*Main> sumL EmptyL
0
*Main> sumL (ConsL 1 EmptyL)
1
*Main> sumL (ConsL 1 (ConsL (2, 3) EmptyL))
6
```

The "magic" is explained in: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/efolds.pdf

For completeness, here's a full definition in terms of the generalized `fold` as described in the paper:

```
import Prelude hiding (sum, fold)

data List a = EmptyL | ConsL (a, List (a, a))

nest :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
nest f EmptyL          = EmptyL
nest f (ConsL (x, xs)) = ConsL (f x, nest (pair f) xs)

pair :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
pair f (x, y) = (f x, f y)

fold :: a -> ((b, a) -> a) -> ((b, b) -> b) -> List b -> a
fold e f g EmptyL          = e
fold e f g (ConsL (x, xs)) = f (x, fold e f g (nest g xs))

sum :: List Int -> Int
sum = fold 0 (uncurry (+)) (uncurry (+))
```

Comment: Interestingly, we can also use `deriving Functor` to derive `nest` as `fmap` (I was a bit surprised that the autoderiving engine coped with the polymorphic recursion!).

Comment: @chi (Haven't tried but) I think you can even derive `Foldable` and get `sum` for free

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Indeed you can! I just tried it, and it works.

Comment: That's what I want!! I thought that this was going to be much difficult.

Comment: @chi I know I can derive Foldable, but how can I give a definition for fold of a nested datatype like this?

Comment: @FedericoSawady Foldable is essentially `toList`, and the answer below gives a possible implementation. You might want to put the elements in the list in a different order.

Comment: @FedericoSawady The paper I cited in the answer has the definition of fold you're looking for.

Comment: I read this paper: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/richard.bird/online/BirdMeertens98Nested.pdf. It says "but one still cannot define important
generic functions, such as fold, over nested types". Why?

Comment: Sorry, It is impossible without Rank-2 types. Thank you.

Comment: @FedericoSawady That is not true; see my edited answer. No extensions are required.

Comment: That's true, I do not understand Bird's paper then.

Comment: What about a version in terms of the "efficient fold" in the paper?

Answer (score 3):

The data type you have is not really for lists, more like complete binary trees. You can convert the trees you have to ordinary lists like this:

```
toList :: List a -> [a]
toList EmptyL = []
toList (ConsL x xs) = x:uncurry (++) (unzip (toList xs))
```

Not the most efficient code and the ordering is a bit arbitrary, but it should work. If you want the sum or anything else you can just use `sum . toList`.

Note that your `lenL` function does not compute the length of the resulting list, but rather the depth of the original tree. If you want the number of elements in the tree you can use `length . toList`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sum` is a method of `Foldable`, let's see how we'd implement `foldMap`:

```
data List a = EmptyL | ConsL a (List (a,a))

instance Foldable List where
  foldMap _ EmptyL = mempty
  foldMap f (ConsL a as) = f a <> foldMap (\(x,y) -> f x <> f y) as
```

We can write `sumL = getSum . foldMap Sum`.